# change 2 byte in a string

Tags: python, string

I'd like to change 2 byte in a string like this:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Let's imagine I want to replace `'RS'` by 11, I know how to do it with one byte like [:], but for 2 or more in the middle of the string ?

Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like homework. You may want to show your attempt first.

Comment: Hmmm... how do you replace a single byte in a string?  Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you can't change them. You have to make a new string from parts of the old one:

```
>>> az= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> az= az[:17]+'11'+az[19:]
>>> az
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ11TUVWXYZ'
```

although depending one what you're doing there may be a more appropriate way of handling it than relying on fixed indices, eg.

```
>>> 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.replace('RS', '11', 1)
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ11TUVWXYZ'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [string.replace()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

```
>>> import string
>>> az = string.lowercase
>>> az = az.replace('rs', '11')
>>> az
'abcdefghijklmnopq11tuvwxyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a trick question, see **"how to do it with one byte"**:

```
>>> st="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
>>> st="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".replace("R","1").replace("S","1")
>>> print st
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ11TUVWXYZ
```